# How to select Low Reorder set from content of {segment_n}?

Tags: low-seg2cat, low-reorder

I have a set of categories within a single group that I apply to entries in a channel to differentiate different classes of document (FAQs, Case-Studies etc.).

I've set up a listing page that uses Low Segment2Cat to pull just the channel entries within a particular category into a list.  The channel tag looks like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="resources" category="{segment_2_category_id}" dynamic="no" require_entry="no"}
```

This works just fine, but I would like to reorder the entries pulled by this request.  So I've created a Low Reorder set to do this for each category - so there is a reorder set called "faqs" that reorders the resource entries with category "faqs" - in total one Low Reorder set for each relevant category, each named the same as the category_url.

With all this set up, I had hoped that I could then use the {segment_2} value to select which Low Reorder set to pull list entries from - and so get them in the right order.  However, this tag-pair

```
{exp:low_reorder:entries set="{segment_2}"}
```

simply doesn't work - it produces no results at all.

Anyone got any ideas how I can get this tag-pair to work?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cases like this, it is good practice to turn on the template debugger and look for any messages that might indicate why the tag returns no results.

First off, `{segment_2}` must be identical to the Low Reorder set name. If it isn't, then no results will be returned.

If the name is correct, but the set has the option of "Show entries per single category" enabled, then a category ID is required as well. If no category="" param is set, then no results will be returned.